# For loop works irregularly

Tags: javascript, html

I've following code. The second for-loop replacing "time" with modified date works irregularly and did not show an error. Most of the time it doesn't run at all, but sometimes it does. I have to refresh the page up to 5 times until the date is displayed. The output of `console.log(datumFields[i])` is not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" id="albumSet"></div>
<script>
        fetch('list.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
            
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById('albumSet');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                
                let showCol = `<div class="col">
                    <div class="card shadow-sm">
                        <div class="row g-0">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" height="400px" role="img" src="${data[i].img_link}" alt="${data[i].name}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">${data[i].name}</h5>
                                    <a href="${data[i].link}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button></a>
                                    <small class="text-muted crdatum">time</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
                mainContainer.innerHTML += showCol;
            };
        };

        var lastMod = null;
        fetch('list.json').then(function (response) {
            lastMod = response.headers.get('Last-Modified');
            console.log(lastMod.toString());
            var datumFields = document.getElementsByClassName('crdatum');
            console.log(datumFields);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < datumFields.length; i++) {
                console.log(datumFields[i]);
                datumFields[i].innerHTML = lastMod.toString();
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I left out the styling part of the HTML.

Below is a part of the list.json file.

```json
[{"name": "A Couple of Cuckoos", "link": "https://www.crunchyroll.com/de/a-couple-of-cuckoos", "img_link": "https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4/90f4219b0eb5aa6acf74e761b30b52cb1650713466_full.jpg"}, {"name": "86 EIGHTY-SIX", "link": "https://www.crunchyroll.com/de/86-eighty-six", "img_link": "https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire1/e912a5b800502bb400e7dfa454f521431633316826_full.jpg"}, {"name": "Accel World", "link": "https://www.crunchyroll.com/de/accel-world", "img_link": "https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4/ae4c67ecb34c76379beb0a072ef4205d1575414444_full.jpg"}, {"name": "Akashic Records of Bastard Magic Instructor", "link": "https://www.crunchyroll.com/de/akashic-records-of-bastard-magic-instructor", "img_link": "https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire2/691011d134b441ab95ca1bc0ac85095e1493152833_full.jpg"}, {"name": "Amagi Brilliant Park", "link": "https://www.crunchyroll.com/de/amagi-brilliant-park", "img_link": "https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4/c86883b9efc479469371d4fdea72720a1432769696_full.jpg"}]
```

Please let me know if there are any details missing to answer or understand my question.

Comment: Why don't you modify the date directly in the `appendData` function? Then you also save a round trip to needing to re-query and update the DOM that you have just made.

Comment: Could I ask you to show me what that would look like? I had already tried to pass the response not only json data but also the headers. Then nothing worked anymore.

Comment: I guess the problem is a race condition between the two fetch requests.  The outcome depends on which request finishes first.  And refreshing the page is like rolling dice where the outcome is not always the same.  If you combine all the code into a single fetch as @Terry suggested that would fix the problem.

Comment: I believe you, but I do not know how. As I wrote before, nothing works (no error either) when I pass response to appendData and share there. But also if I divide before and pass 2 values.

Comment: Might be irrelevant but when I encounter a problem where something is not updating on page refresh, I load the page again in a new browser tab. I think browsers simple reshow what they already have if they think the page has not changed since last loaded in the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terry and Yogi gave the right tip as well as the right explanation why the error happened. What I didn't know was how to pass multiple values to appendData without changing the json object. Here is the solution. I deleted the last for loop completely.

```js
fetch('list.json')
    .then(response => response.json()
    .then(data => appendData(data, response.headers.get('Last-Modified'))
    ))
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
    });

function appendData(data, lastMod) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('albumSet');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let showCol = `<div class="col">
            <div class="card shadow-sm">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" height="400px" role="img" src="${data[i].img_link}" alt="${data[i].name}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${data[i].name}</h5>
                            <a href="${data[i].link}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button></a>
                            <small class="text-muted crdatum">${lastMod}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
        mainContainer.innerHTML += showCol;
    };
};
```